# Add array into an array of object in angular typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to push an array of string into an array of object --> `Accessright[];`

```
selectedAccessRights: String[];
accessRights: Accessright[];


for (var i = 0; i < this.numOfPages; i++) {
  this.selectedAccessRights.push(this.selectedPages[i].entityName);
  //I have tried to the following as well, but it doesn't add everything to the accessRights object. Only the last element
  //this.accessRights[i].entityName = this.selectedPages[i].entityName;
}

this.accessRights = this.accessRights.push(this.selectedAccessRights);
```

But the above line gives me an error

> Argument of type '`String[]`' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   '`Accessright`'.   Type '`String[]`' is missing the following properties
>   from type '`Accessright`': `accessRightId`, `entityName`, `entityAttribute`

Also tried add and insert from other post but didn't work for me.

Honestly out of ideas and debugged for so long. Would appreciate if anyone can take a look.

Update:

```
38: //Accessright response format
accessGroup: {accessGroupId: 1, accessGroupName: "AdminGroup", accessRights: Array(0), staffs: Array(0)}
accessRightId: 39
entityAttribute: ["charts"]
entityName: "EditDashboard"
__proto__: Object


39: Array(12) //My array
0:
accessRightId: 0
entityName: "Staff"
isDisabled: undefined
1:
accessRightId: 1
entityName: "AccessGroup"
isDisabled: undefined
__proto__: Object
```

Tried the any[] method but it's not working as my webservices is expecting an access right object.

Comment: Please provide the definition of the `Accessright` type.

Comment: Can you Share your code on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)

Comment: To me, it looks like you're trying to push a string array into a Array of Accessright that clearly doesn't support it. You need to either modify the definition of AccessRight, or make the variable type any,

Comment: @KiranMistry will try to do it soon

Comment: What does `this.selectedPages[i].entityName` return?

Comment: @Mason, you need initialize an array before push `selectedAccessRights: String[]=[]` see the **=[]** else the array is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updates:

I decided to change my backend to receive the array of string elements instead.

It was much easier than trying to insert an array of string into an object then send it to the backend.

Answer (score 1):

```
selectedAccessRights: string;
accessRights: any = [];

   for (var i = 0; i < this.numOfPages; i++) {

       this.selectedAccessRights = this.selectedPages[i].entityName;
       this.accessRights = this.accessRights.push(this.selectedAccessRights);

     }
```

Comment: please explain your code with solution it would be better

Answer (score 1):

the push method of array returns the length of the array after the push is done, so firs of all its not returning a string[]. Also, when you push a value in array it added it to that array.
So, change this.accessRights = this.accessRights.push(this.selectedAccessRights);

to

this.accessRights.push(this.selectedAccessRights);

Please refer the below link for detailed explanation of push method
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push